# Note taking software that allows to list organic chemistry reactions and their reaction mechanisms

Tags: note-taking

What I am looking for is a software, which will allow me to list the reactions for organic chemistry from my syllabus. When I click on a list item, it will open up the reaction mechanism.Like a link to any other document , or maybe expand there itself, or a popup .

Android or Windows (preferably Android).
Paid or unpaid anything .

Comment: What do you expect from this app, what "normal" text editors cannot do?

Comment: Linking mechanism to list items

Comment: If I understand correctly, those links are not meant to open a web page, instead they should open another local note (Wiki).

Comment: @martinstoeckli Yes, Exactly , kind of like a second document, or expand a bit in the same document

Answer (score 1):

VirtualChemist (https://www.rosoft.website) may fit your need. Using reactant Lewis structure as the only user input, it can (1) describe detailed reaction mechanisms at the level of electron flows in elementary reaction steps, ensuring that all reaction steps are not only atom and electron balanced but also atom-mapped; and (2) track molecular 3-D structure changes in every elementary reaction steps. In each reaction step, users can start animation and look at 3-D structures from different perspectives for each molecules and isomers, to aid the understanding of stereochemistry.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you mean by "open up the reaction mechanism", but if you mean to hyperlink to another note, then consider wiki software such as Zim (https://zim-wiki.org/).  Zim allows you to hierarchically structure your notes, and also hyperlink between wiki pages.  It includes an equation editor plugin that might be useful for representing the organic chemistry reactions.

Zim runs on Windows and Linux.  There is no Android application but the individual pages are just text files, so it is possible to edit the pages if they have been synced to your Android device from a desktop computer (e.g., using Dropbox).